# wordpress: detect plugins and themes screens activation

Tags: php, wordpress, action, addition

I need to detect when user goes to :

> Plugins -> Installed Plugins  and Appearance -> Themes

in wordpress admin.

Something like :

```
add_action("core_upgrade_preamble", "action_core_upgrade_preamble")
```

Comment: if they goes to that section what you wish to do ?

Comment: I'd like to add some content to that sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

**Option 1**:
Use the callback $hook, first get the `$hook` of the page using this:

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style($hook) {
        var_dump($hook);
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

Check your page in the browser you should get the string name, then you can use:

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style($hook) {
        // Load only on my specific page
        if($hook != 'page_hook_i_got') {
                return;
        }
        //DO MY LOGIC   

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

**Option 2**:
Use `get_current_screen();`

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'this_screen' );

function this_screen() {

    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    if( $current_screen ->id === "widgets" ) {

        // Run some code, only on the admin widgets page

    }

}
```

you will need to do a `var_dump` to find the `id` of the page, like in option 1, you can find more info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen).